# Mobile, desktop, and web application with server side

Tags: c#, java, android, asp.net, .net

I want to know what I should use for developing of a server side application which receive interrogations from a web , mobile or desktop application.Do I can use for this C# ASP.NET MVC or Java EE, or PHP? And how this communication it can be done through server side application?

Comment: You can use any language you want.  Everything looks the same over HTTP.

Comment: To start, I'd build a few "Hello, World" type examples in each of the mentioned technologies. And do a little research about them on their Wikipedia pages etc. Pick the one that appeals best to you.

Comment: if you can choose between C# and java then choose C#. It's [way better](http://www.slideshare.net/jeffz/why-java-sucks-and-c-rocks-final)

Comment: @HighCore , now I learn ASP.NET MVC but I don t know how make the link between MVC and a native mobile application or a desktop one, because ASP MVC has just View part which make ling to a web page. This is my question

Comment: @AlinVelican: That's what Web API is for.

Comment: @SLaks so with Web API I can make the link between a server side application and a mobile one? In whatever technology i want to use?

Comment: Web API allows you to easily define a RESTful HTTP API that you can call from your mobile apps or SPAs.

Comment: If you wish to just have the MVC project, you can define endpoints in the controllers and decorate them with the Attribute that matches your http method (e.g. [HttpPost]) and then if you make a post from anywhere to that endpoint (using whatever URL your have routed to that endpoint) then it will allow this. As suggested in other comments though, Web API is probably the best way to go.